# Display different cells based on data type in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have three different types of cells with different `content size` (containing `image`, `label` and `button`) in `UICollectionview`. I am getting data from web services. I want to show correct cell based on these types.

Comment: due to lack of Reputation i am not able to share cell image.

Comment: Good for you. What do you intend to do with said cells?

Comment: You can post your image here http://postimage.org/

Comment: I want to use the cell to display contains based on data from server so how will i know which cell to display

Comment: Like Facebook post type cell

Comment: Link for Image is http://postimg.org/image/mg2kvlb4t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you register nibs of layouts for your cells:

```
[collectionView registerNib:myCellTypeImageNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyModelTypeImageCellIdentifier"];
[collectionView registerNib:myCellTypeLabelNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyModelTypeLabelCellIdentifier"];
[collectionView registerNib:myCellTypeButtonNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyModelTypeButtonCellIdentifier"];
```

Then return them appropriately:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyModel *modelObject = self.dataArray[indexPath.item];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = nil;
    switch (modelObject.type) {
        case MyModelTypeImage:
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyModelTypeImageCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //adjust cell
            break;
        case MyModelTypeLabel:
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyModelTypeLabelCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //adjust cell
            break;
        case MyModelTypeButton:
            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyModelTypeButtonCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //adjust cell
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions, I had bought i created cells in storyboard by giving number of Items as 3 and gave different Identifier for  each cell

Comment: Then you can omit `registerNib` calls. Other code is still fine

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Note: `indexpath`

For example. Add all the images in to an `array`.

```
self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first.jpg",
                                 @"second.jpg",
                                 @"third.jpg",
                                 @"last.jpg",nil]
```

Then in `cellForRow...` do the following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // configure cell
    ...
    cell.myImageView = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row;
}
```

Comment: Three different size of cells with different layout